# TFS configuration policy creation using API in C#

Tags: c#, api, tfs, tfs-sdk

I'm trying to create a new branch policy using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Policy.WebApi Library.
my Code is:
[image: code snippet detailed below]

variable info:

json - contains the setting in the policy configuration

connection - is the VSSConnection to our TFS server

TFSProject - is the project name in the TFS

the error i get the is not showing anything in my searches, i would appreciate some examples for how to create a new policy in TFS

code:

```
var json = "{\"statusName\": \"" + StatusNameForBlock + "\",\"statusGenre\": \"ci\",\"authorId\": null,\"invalidateOnSourceUpdate\": false,\"policyApplicability\": null,\"scope\": [{\"refName\": \"refs/heads/master\",\"matchKind\": \"Exact\"}]}";
            JObject jToken = new JObject(JObject.Parse(json));
            var newPolicy = new PolicyConfiguration();
            var policyType = new PolicyTypeRef();
            policyType.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            newPolicy.Type = policyType;
            newPolicy.Settings = jToken;

            var gitPolicyHttpClient = connection.GetClient<PolicyHttpClient>();
            var policyCreated = gitPolicyHttpClient.CreatePolicyConfigurationAsync(newPolicy, TFSProject).Result;
```

exception: VssServiceException: Type with id '98813712-70a4-4937-b139-9a3654c9795f' does not exist

Answer (score 0):

You could use Rest API to create a new branch policy.

```
POST https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/policy/configurations/{configurationId}?api-version=5.0
```

Use these APIs to define policies for your projects. Configurations associate a type, such as "Required reviewers", with specific settings, such as "For pull requests with files named *.dll targeting the master branch in the xxx Git repository, add the Source-Controlled Binaries Team as a required reviewer".

[Policy Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/policy/configurations/create?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0) for your reference.

For more details, you could also take a look at this blog-- [Configuring standard policies for all repositories in Azure Repos](https://jessehouwing.net/azure-repos-git-configuring-standard-policies-on-repositories/)

Comment: that's not best practice. i Solved my problem, will post the answer soon.

Comment: @OriWiesel Always better when you fix it yourself; as you understand how it works!:) Please feel free to share your solution here and then mark your reply as an answer, which will also helps others in the community.